Printer prints only candy floss
Printer is Monoprice MP Voxel running PLA using MP Flashprint software.
Printer worked great for about 20 hours, then after a hiatus, started printing candy floss. The printer used to work fine with all default software settings and now doesn't work with all default settings.
The first layer (of the raft) looks great, but nothing after that sticks. I tried:

switching to new filament,
did 2 cold pulls (not sure I did these right), cold pulls after the first look clean, I get a conical end to the pull without a nipple,
tried varying layer thickness,
varying print speed,
increasing temperature,
cranking up extrusion ratio to the max of 125 % didn't seem to do anything,
commanding the filament to extrude and retract appears pretty smooth,
printing colder didn't seem to help either.

But this didn't help solve the issue.
See below image of 1 x 1 x 0.5 cm cube with all defaults on software. What am I looking at here?
Print settings:

I print in PLA at 210 °C (I also tried 215).
The print bed is set to 50 °C.
I use a print cooling fan at 100 %.
The layer height I set to 0.18 mm, the line width (0.4 mm is 'path width') from the 0.4 mm nozzle.
The Printing Speed is set to 40 mm/s (max) for walls and 60 mm/s for infill.
My retraction is 5 mm/off at 25 mm/s.

Photo with default settings:

The following is with infill set to 100 % (above is 15 %) and no raft:

Filament diameter is correct at 1.75 mm. The closest thing I see to 'flow multiplier' is 'extrusion ratio', which is set to 109 % (!; but that's the default). I tried printing at 200 °C, and it looked similar (but the part pulled off the platform halfway through).

Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! You are definitely under extruding! Please check if your extruder is skipping, if the filament rolls of easily from the spool, the filament is not entangled, the extruder is cleaned. Basically, make sure that there is virtually no option for the filament to slip. If you checked all that, post an dere if it is fixed or add what you tried to the question to prevent answers delving into these possibilities. Tried a different slicer?

Cura won't communicate with the printer for some reason, although I could use a USB stick, I guess.

I ordered a new nozzle assembly, which came before the cleaning kit. Fixed the issue right up.
The Flashforge nozzle seems to be embedded into an injection-molded assembly, so dropping it into a vat of solvent to clean isn't viable. I'd call that a pretty major downside.
